# Split Data with format through VBA

Tags: excel, split, vba

Please help with below requirement.

attached 2 image, one is Data and another one is requirement.

Data= we are getting data in this format
Requirement= i have to convert date in this format.

Please help with VA on priority.

[Requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98ujd.png)
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0Iia.png)

Comment: want a VBA coding to make the Requirement sheet from Data sheet.

Comment: I'm honestly trying not to to be rude but do you want my permission to write one? Are you a programmer (professional or enthusiastic)? If not, do you want help finding one? Please help us understand your own situation in order that we can render assistance.

Comment: i am not a programmer, please help to get the coding

Comment: what's wrong with the code I pointed you at?